# Instagram Graph API - How to get url of shared media from Instagram Inbox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to grab the url of an instagram post/story that has been sent to my inbox with the Graph API. I'm receiving text and other attachments like images and videos correctly. When I perform a GET request with a message ID of a message that contains shared media like a post or story, the attachments and shares object is empty. I can get most of the other fields in this list: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/message but for some reason attachments and shares are always empty when the message is a shared post/story.

All I want is the url of the shared post/story, like the one you get when you Copy Link from a post/story in the Instagram App. Something like: https://www.instagram.com/p/Cz91G2aA-k2/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

Here is the query I'm putting into Graph API Explorer: GET/v18.0/{message-id}?fields=attachments,shares

All I get returned back is the message ID. I was expecting to get an attachment or shared object with the details of the shared media post/story.

I've tried a number of solutions to get the correct url, including setting up webhooks. The closest I got was getting the url of the image/video asset in the payload of the webhook response. (Something like: https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=17985658535528245&signature=AbwzHB15sNyHStYZZmw3_cHMyb0a61k6753z6HaTVbGHvLYbqO1kT8bpzbTGLpJGVyjAo-GOkYUyvA-VwKAF_PipEZmwq41IKrlkrZqwqYxGp583CuviMCML3EklKc3wIwCH2mbi47gm4zd_k0c0mcHPWgBmnWUvA0txK6tqTOmB6Zxs3TxiAaIpyDSMCWkovE5ZCrRGjklraueJasPWq2ZVW9DfHeJR)

But I want the link for the post itself, not just the image/video asset.

Is this even possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I was able to get the url as well be using the endpoint /MESSAGE-ID?fields=shares{id,link}
But this only returns the link and nothing else. I want to get the post id.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, but firstly make sure you are requesting from a user within your sandbox. Then, you need to add an edge, so the url becomes:
[https://graph.facebook.com/{GRAPH_API_VERSION}/{message_id}/attachments?fields={fields}&platform=instagram&access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7BGRAPH_API_VERSION%7D/%7Bmessage_id%7D/attachments?fields=%7Bfields%7D&platform=instagram&access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

So the /attachments gets added to the url. This will direct you to the attachments edge, however I will say that you might still get an empty data array. (Happens to me, haven't been able to fix yet)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).